# Undefined method 'createQueryBuilder'

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, api-platform.com, doctrine-query

I'm getting error for "**$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();**" this line in my project file . Can someone help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwjIF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()` is getting an instance of `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager`, which doesn't have `createQueryBuilder` function.

From the manager, you can fetch repository for the entity you want to fetch. For example:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('App:MyClass')->createQueryBuidler()
```